# update mysql usando array

Tags: php, mysql, array, loop, sql-update

estou com problemas para inserir um array no banco de dados...
tentei esse script mas ele só insere o ultimo id do array;

```
<?php
$_conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vbt_posteds");
$id_ind = $_POST["inds"];

$id = "57";

$dados = count($id_ind);

for($i=0; $i<$dados; $i++){

$idfnc = $id_ind[$i];

$sql = mysqli_query($_conexao,"UPDATE dados_inds SET id_inds='$idfnc'
                    WHERE id_user='$id'");              
}

echo "editado com sucesso";

?>
```

eu quero atualizar uma tabela relacional com 4 linhas com os ids

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>id_user</td><td>id_inds</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>57</td><td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>57</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>57</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>57</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: @Bacco acho que seria melhor ele usar um for($id_ind as $idfnc) né o que acha ?

Comment: não vi isto quando editei não apareceu nenhuma outra edição sorry

Comment: User14579 você está fazendo vários updates no id 57 com a sua lógica. Obviamente só o último vai ficar visível, pois a cada update o anterior é sobreescrito. INSERT é para por novos registros, UPDATE é para atualizar um já existente.

Comment: @Otto então, como o autor não explicou direito o que ele quer atualizar ou inserir e em qual coluna, fica dificil adivinhar. De qualquer forma, a query tem problema (sendo no for ou foreach). Obviamente que o foreach fica com código mais limpo, mas é melhor focar na lógica da query em si agora, senão capaz de complicar ainda mais :)

Comment: user14579 seria legal [edit] a pergunta e explicar o que é que tem nas variáveis e a lógica de funcionamento, pois aumenta a chance de uma resposta que resolva seu problema.

Comment: @Baccon, pode ser que as variáveis dele estejam trocadas também, poderia ser assim a _query_ `UPDATE dados_inds SET id_inds='$id' WHERE id_user='$idfnc'`, mas só saberemos quando ele editar a pergunta e explicar melhor a lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Se você está tentando atualizar dados de uma tabela relacional você precisa de uma chave composta ou uma chave primária para identificar qual registro vai ser atualizado.

Abaixo indico como ficaria os registros em sua tabela de relacionamento com uma chave primária.

```
 id | id_user | id_inds
 1  | 57      | 2
 2  | 57      | 4
 3  | 57      | 5
 4  | 57      | 8
```

O campo id pode ser `auto-increment`.

Para atualizar um registro você iria usar o campo `id` como referência.

Ficando da seguinte maneira assim:

```
$_conexao = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'vbt_posteds' );

$all_ids = $_POST[ 'ids' ];
$all_id_ind = $_POST[ 'inds' ];

foreach( $all_ids as $key => $id ) {
    $id_ind = $all_id_ind[ $key ];

    $query = "UPDATE `dados_inds` SET `id_inds` = '$id_ind' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $sql = mysqli_query( $_conexao, $query );              
}

echo "editado com sucesso";
```

Note que não usei o campo `id_user` pois ele não será atualizado e não serve como referencia para identificar o registro que devo atualizar.

Caso não possa adicionar esse campo primário em sua tabela relacional, recomendo excluir todos os registros relacionados a um usuário e depois inserir o relacionamento novo.

```
$_conexao = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'vbt_posteds' );

$id_user = 57;
$all_id_ind = $_POST[ 'inds' ];

// Excluo todos os relacionamentos do usuário
$query = "DELETE FROM `dados_inds` WHERE `id_user` = '$id_user'";
$sql = mysqli_query( $_conexao, $query );     

foreach( $all_id_ind as $id_ind ) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `dados_inds` ( `id_inds`, `id_user` ) VALUES ( '$id_ind', 'id_user' )";
    $sql = mysqli_query( $_conexao, $query );              
}

echo "editado com sucesso";
```

Comment: é realmente no primeiro exemplo eu precisaria da chave primaria mesmo pra indicar especificamente onde atualizar, mas fiquei com a outra opção de deletar depois inserir, achei mais fácil e pratico...  valeu brigadão!!!